# How to retrieve the search_path set for an function using a query on information_schema?

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple functions for each schema that have `search_path` defined on the creation in this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION the_schema.update_complete_url(updateLang bigint) RETURNS boolean AS $$
DECLARE
   tree_row record;
BEGIN
   // body of function
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SET search_path=the_schema,public,pg_temp;
```

The `search_path` is defined so that I do not need to prefix each table in the function body with `the_schema.` which makes it easier for me to maintain those functions.

Now I have a maintaining/migration script that tests if certain functions exits and have the correct settings. Retrieving the function itself is not a problem as it would look that way:

```
SELECT * FROM "information_schema"."routines" 
    WHERE "routine_type"='FUNCTION' AND "specific_schema"='the_schema';
```

And querying for the parameters is also no problem using `"information_schema"."parameters"`, but where is the `SET search_path=the_schema,public,pg_temp` part stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK it is not available in information_schema.

You can get it thru pg_catalog, but it is PostgreSQL specific:

```
select unnest(proconfig) from pg_proc where proname = 'function_name';
```

Comment: The script is postgresql specific anyway, so this will do it.

Comment: ... it might be better to use `WHERE oid = 'the_schema.update_complete_url(bigint)'::regprocedure`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks. I'll take that into account.